# Insert into table via relation id's

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Below I have the `Equipt` entity it has three columns `createdById`, `tribeId`, `userId`.

I am trying to save a new row using the id's of each entity, and not the entities themselves:

This doesn't work:

```
let e = connection.getRepository(Equipt);

const check = await e.save({
    userId: 1,
    tribeId: 1,
    createdById: 1,
})
```

This works:

```
let e = connection.getRepository(Equipt);

const check = await e.save({
    user: user,
    tribe: tribe,
    createdBy: adminUser,
})
```

Entity:

```
import {ManyToOne, RelationId, JoinColumn, Entity} from "typeorm";
import {User} from './User';
import { Base } from "../base";
import { Tribe } from "./Tribe";

@Entity('Equipts')
export class Equipt extends Base {

    @ManyToOne(type => User, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn()
    createdBy: User;

    @RelationId((Equipt: Equipt) => Equipt.createdBy)
    createdById: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Tribe, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn()
    Tribe: Tribe;

    @RelationId((Equipt: Equipt) => Equipt.Tribe)
    TribeId: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => User, { nullable: false })
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User;

    @RelationId((Equipt: Equipt) => Equipt.user)
    userId: number;

}
```

Is there any way to insert using id's without having the pass the entire entity?